# How to trian the model provided by gluoncv on my own image dataset?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation, mxnet

The repository is https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models. I am doing the semantic segmentation task. Could anybody please share me a demo?

Comment: sorry, I give the wrong url. It might be https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-cv

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of the Gluon CV toolkit includes a working example of applying semantic segmentation: 
https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/model_zoo/segmentation.html#semantic-segmentation